# Creating Microsoft Word objects in an ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7.5, office-interop

I have an IIS 7.5 on a 2008 R2 server running an application using ASP.NET with framework 4.0. The application creates a word report, first it opens an HTML web page, selects all of the content and copies it to a word template and then it saves it in a location. If I run the application form Visual Studio Express 2010, the application runs fine and does everything it should. But when I run it from IIS the application hangs. I have the InternetExplorer object and the Word object set to visible so I can see what's happening (normally is set to false), and no Internet Explorer is visible or Word even though I can see in the task manager that the processes are up and running. If I let it run an exception will be thrown that says:

> "This command is not available because no document is open"

When the first action is made with the code is a `word.ActiveDocument.Select();` this is after `word.Documents.Open();` If I put a `word.Activate();` before a `word.Documents.Open();`another exception will be thrown that says:

> "Cannot activate application"

our AppPool is set to our local user with Super Admin rights, the folders have both users, the AppPool and the local user, with all rights, I have done the DCOM Setting to defaults and added missing users. I do know that Microsoft advises against Office Automation but for now we are using this.

I guess the problem is with some permissions but I don't know where else to look. Also it's very strange that the applications are set to visible and the processes are shown in the Task Manager to be up and running but not even the IE window is shown.

**EDIT :**

I will change the code to use OpenXML SDK as all the information that I've encountered and comments leads to this, but I will leave the question open to see if anyone has more information. Also the other part of the question was that the IE Object is created, initialized and the process is up, but no window is visible even though the object is set to visible anyone can shine some light on this?

I'm using the

`InternetExplorer` Class.

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: Thank you, I do know that its not supported by Microsoft and that is not recommended, but this is the code that has been given to me and right know I don't have the power to change it. I will do it, but once I have permission. For now my task is to make it work and I seek help thanks!

Comment: You will not make it work. That's the point. Please have your supervisors read this comment. It cannot "work". It can sometimes be made to seem to work, until you realize that it's not working. For instance, it may seem to work for documents without pictures, but as soon as a document has a picture in it, it fails. Or one font vs. a different font. Really, tell your supervisor that _I_ said "don't _do_ that". This is from hard experience, not "because Microsoft says so".

Comment: Thank you I will let them know, just on a side note they have been using this application for various years and at least 20 users, we are migrating it to a new server and here is where we are having problems. The new server has the same configuration and specs as the previous one.

Comment: I've been there. This is the part about seeming to work. Most likely, the users are used to the bugs in the application and know how to work around them. If they realized what's really going on here, they would be frightened. It's not a small problem or a "Microsoft knows best" issue. You're basically mixing two totally different programming models and expecting it to work. Briefly, the Office products are _desktop_ applications and assume they're running in a _desktop_ environment. Server environments are very different. It's a bad idea to violate assumptions.